# Remote debugging vagrant asp.net webform site

Tags: asp.net, vagrant, remote-debugging, omnisharp

I'm not sure this is possible from the docs, but can you remote debug an vagrant ASP.NET webforms site using omnisharp remote debugger? I can't find much info on this anywhere

EDIT:
Trying to setup omnisharp for VScode
https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Attaching-to-remote-processes

I'm using this vagrant setup
https://github.com/dmitry-zaets/vagrantfile-windows-iis-mssql/blob/master/Vagrantfile

I also added ASP.Net to this box

```
DISM /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ISAPIFilter
DISM /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ISAPIExtensions
DISM /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-NetFxExtensibility
DISM /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Vagrant create and setup ordinary VM or we can see on it as remote PC. If you provide more details, which guest \ host you are going to use, your Vagrantfile, then help will be more specific.

Comment: Sure, I can post my vagrant file but I'm really looking to see how VSCode omnisharp debugger can remote in. I'm not sure on the settings

Comment: I've posted the vagrant setup I'm using as well as the omnisharp setup

Comment: Did I lose you @Vadim

Comment: I've not saw your messages because you not mention me, unfortunately, I can't help you here because сan just recommend to follow omnisharp instructions